# Break document sections into list for export Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, parsing, document

I am very new to Python, and I am trying to break some legal documents into sections for export into SQL.  I need to do two things:

1. Define the section numbers by the table of contents, and
2. Break up the document given the defined section numbers

The table of contents lists section numbers: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.

Then the document itself is broken up by those section numbers:
1.1 "...Text...",
1.2 "...Text...",
1.3 "...Text...", etc.

Similar to the chapters of a book, but delimited by ascending decimal numbers.

I have the document parsed using Tika, and I've been able to create a list of sections with some basic regex:

```
import tika
import re

from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('test.pdf')
content = (parsed["content"])

headers = re.findall("[0-9]*[.][0-9]",content)
```

Now I need to do something like this:

```
splitsections = content.split() by headers

var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(splitsections))
query_string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s);' % var_string
cursor.execute(query_string, splitsections)
```

Sorry if all this is unclear.  Still very new to this.

Any help you can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything tested except the last part with DB. Also the code can be improved, but this is another task. The main task is done.

In the list `split_content` there are all pieces of info you wanted (i.e. the text between 2.1 and 2.2, then 2.2 and 2.3, and so on, EXCLUDING num+name of sections itself (i.e. excluding `2.1 Continuation`, `2.2 Name` and so on).

I replaced `tika` by `PyPDF2`, as `tika` does not provide instruments needed for this task (i.e. I did not find how to provide the num of page I need and get its content).

```
def get_pdf_content(pdf_path,
                    start_page_table_contents, end_page_table_contents,
                    first_parsing_page, last_phrase_to_stop):
    """
    :param pdf_path: Full path to the PDF file
    :param start_page_table_contents: The page where the "Contents table" starts
    :param end_page_table_contents:    The page where the "Contents Table" ends
                                      (i.e. the number of the page where Contents Table ENDs, i.e. not the next one)
    :param first_parsing_page:        The 1st page where we need to start data grabbing
    :param last_phrase_to_stop:       The phrase that tells the code where to stop grabbing.
                                      The phrase must match exactly what is written in PDF.
                                      This phrase will be excluded from the grabbed data.
    :return: 
    """

    # ======== GRAB TABLE OF CONTENTS ========
    start_page = start_page_table_contents
    end_page = end_page_table_contents

    table_of_contents_page_nums = range(start_page-1, end_page)

    sections_of_articles = []  # ['2.1 Continuation', '2.2 Name', ... ]

    open_file = open(pdf_path, "rb")
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_file)

    for page_num in table_of_contents_page_nums:
        page_content = pdf.getPage(page_num).extractText()

        page_sections = re.findall("[\d]+[.][\d][™\s\w;,-]+", page_content)

        for section in page_sections:
            cleared_section = section.replace('\n', '').strip()
            sections_of_articles.append(cleared_section)

    # ======== GRAB ALL NECESSARY CONTENT (MERGE ALL PAGES) ========
    total_num_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
    parsing_pages = range(first_parsing_page-1, total_num_pages)

    full_parsing_content = ''  # Merged pages

    for parsing_page in parsing_pages:
        page_content = pdf.getPage(parsing_page).extractText()
        cleared_page = page_content.replace('\n', '')

        # Remove page num from the start of "page_content"

        # Covers the case with the page 65, 71 and others when the "page_content" starts
        # with, for example, "616.6 Liability to Partners.  (a)  It is understood that"
        # i.e. "61" is the page num and "6.6 Liability ..." is the section data
        already_cleared = False
        first_50_chars = cleared_page[:51]

        for section in sections_of_articles:
            if section in first_50_chars:
                indx = cleared_page.index(section)
                cleared_page = cleared_page[indx:]

                already_cleared = True
                break

        # Covers all other cases
        if not already_cleared:
            page_num_to_remove = re.match(r'^\d+', cleared_page)
            if page_num_to_remove:
                cleared_page = cleared_page[len(str(page_num_to_remove.group(0))):]

        full_parsing_content += cleared_page

    # ======== BREAK ALL CONTENT INTO PIECES ACCORDING TO TABLE CONTENTS ========
    split_content = []

    num_sections = len(sections_of_articles)

    for num_section in range(num_sections):
        start = sections_of_articles[num_section]

        # Get the last piece, i.e. "11.16 FATCA" (as there is no any "end" section after "11.16 FATCA", so we cant use
        # the logic like "grab info between sections 11.1 and 11.2, 11.2 and 11.3 and so on")
        if num_section == num_sections-1:
            end = last_phrase_to_stop

        else:
            end = sections_of_articles[num_section + 1]

        content = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), full_parsing_content).group(1)

        cleared_piece = content.replace('™', "'").strip()
        if cleared_piece[0:3] == '.  ':
            cleared_piece = cleared_piece[3:]

        # There are few appearances of "[Signature Page Follows]", as a "last_phrase_to_stop".
        # We need the text between "11.16 FATCA" and the 1st appearance of "[Signature Page Follows]"
        try:
            indx = cleared_piece.index(end)
            cleared_piece = cleared_piece[:indx]
        except ValueError:
            pass

        split_content.append(cleared_piece)

    # ======== INSERT TO DB ========
    # Did not test this section
    for piece in split_content:
        var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(piece))
        query_string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s);' % var_string
        cursor.execute(query_string, parts)
```

**How to use:** (one of the possible way):

1) Save the code above in `my_pdf_code.py`
2) In the python shell:

```
import path.to.my_pdf_code as the_code
the_code.get_pdf_content('/home/username/Apollo_Investment_Fund_VIII_LPA_S1.pdf', 2, 4, 24, '[Signature Page Follows]')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  I added a link above to a document that represents what "test.pdf" would look like.  The headers would be defined on the table of contents on pages i through iii (2.1, 2.2, etc).  Then, the content to be broken up starts on page 20 (with section 2.1).

Comment: @junkbond916. Do you want to get pieces of the text between section numbers? As I understand, you want to start from the page #20 in order to get text between section 2.1 and 2.2, then between 2.2 and 2.3 and so on. Then the same for each Article\Chapter... (up to section 11.16). Am I right? If so, that's not an easy task :) As I can see from your `re`, you get just section numbers, however in this case section numbers without section names are useless. Need to think how to solve it.

Comment: Hi Titan - you nailed it.  That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  And yes - my code above just produces a list of numbers.  It would be better to have the whole section name (i.e. "2.1 Continuation") to break the document. It's quite a puzzle.  Thanks so much again for taking a look.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @junkbond916, I wrote a code for you. For the future - next time please do as much as possible, because `stackoverflow` does not welcome such things when someone needs to do author's work. Do not forget to accept the answer (under the 2 up\down arrows in front of my answer there is a grey check mark).

Comment: Thanks so much - appreciate the help and advice.